# Getting description when aggregating with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

When we use the aggregation feature on elastic, we get a value of the field we aggregating back but we also want to get the description of that field. We have to use the `sector.id` as other parts of our api uses it later on.
For ex: our data looks like this:

```
[{
   "id":"123"
   "sectors":[{
     "id":"sector-1",
     "name":"Automotive" 
   }]
},
{
   "id":"123"
   "sectors":[{
     "id":"sector-2",
     "name":"Biology" 
   }]
}]
```

When we aggregate over `sectors.id` our response looks like:

```
"aggregations": {
    "sector": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "sector-2",
          "doc_count": 19672
        },
        {
          "key": "sector-1",
          "doc_count": 11699
        }]
      }
  }
```

Is there any way to get `sectors.name` as well as the key in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that `sectors` should a nested field. Now assuming that sector name is unique per sector-id.

You may use [sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations) to figure out the related keys

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sectors": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sectors"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sector_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sectors.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sector_name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "sectors.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```